# C# add items to list in a loop

Tags: c#, for-loop

If multiUPC has more than one value i want to loop split the values and loop through and add each to the model. if i return in the loop it only goes through the loop once. 
I want to create two list items and return both of them once the loop is done.
Here is my Code.

```
 for (int x = 0; x <= multiUPC.Count()-1 ; x ++)
            {

                 return new List<PRM> { new PRM((multiUPC[x]),
                                        this.ModelMap[PRP.GetPropertyName(() => s.SKu)],
                                        this.ModelMap[PRP.GetPropertyName(() => s.UPCD)],
                                        this.ModelMap[PRP.GetPropertyName(() => s.SKUD)],
                                        this.ModelMap[PRP.GetPropertyName(() => s.Dep)]) };

            }


            return null;
```

I want to return all the values from the loop where i currently return null

Thanks

Comment: You are using a `return` in your loop without condition. It can only ever possibly iterate once, as if it gets there, that `return` is telling it to leave the method. You need to declare a list before the loop, `.Add()` your items to the list within the loop, and then return the declared list *after* the loop.

Comment: @up OR use yield return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's find out (with a help of *Linq*) *what* to add:

```
  var source = multiUPC
    .Select((item, x) => new PRM(
       multiUPC[x],
       ModelMap[PRP.GetPropertyName(() => s.SKu)], 
       ModelMap[PRP.GetPropertyName(() => s.UPCD)],
       ModelMap[PRP.GetPropertyName(() => s.SKUD)],
       ModelMap[PRP.GetPropertyName(() => s.Dep)]
      ));
```

then decide *how* to add, e.g. if you want just return the `source` as `List<PRM>`:

```
  var result = source
    .ToList();
```

if you want to add into existing list:

```
  List<PRM> result = ...

  ...

  result.AddRange(source);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = new List<List<PRM>>();
for (int x = 0; x <= multiUPC.Count()-1 ; x ++)
            {

                 result.Add( new List<PRM> { new PRM((multiUPC[x]),
                               this.ModelMap[PRP.GetPropertyName(() => s.SKu)],
                               this.ModelMap[PRP.GetPropertyName(() => s.UPCD)],
                               this.ModelMap[PRP.GetPropertyName(() => s.SKUD)],
                               this.ModelMap[PRP.GetPropertyName(() => s.Dep)]) });

            }

return result
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return a list of items in a loop you can use **yield**.

take a look [at this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx)

Then if your return type is list of list you can use yield  like this

```
for (int x = 0; x <= multiUPC.Count()-1 ; x ++)
            {

                 return yield new List<PRM> { new PRM((multiUPC[x]),
                                        this.ModelMap[PRP.GetPropertyName(() => s.SKu)],
                                        this.ModelMap[PRP.GetPropertyName(() => s.UPCD)],
                                        this.ModelMap[PRP.GetPropertyName(() => s.SKUD)],
                                        this.ModelMap[PRP.GetPropertyName(() => s.Dep)]) };

            }
```

But if you need only one list with the values that you are filling in the list use

```
for (int x = 0; x <= multiUPC.Count()-1 ; x ++)
            {

             return yield new PRM((multiUPC[x]),
                                    this.ModelMap[PRP.GetPropertyName(() => s.SKu)],
                                    this.ModelMap[PRP.GetPropertyName(() => s.UPCD)],
                                    this.ModelMap[PRP.GetPropertyName(() => s.SKUD)],
                                    this.ModelMap[PRP.GetPropertyName(() => s.Dep)]) ;

        }
```